# multiple Orchard CMS blog autoroute

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Lets say I have 2 blogs: BlogOne and BlogTwo. I want the autoroute to be the same text as the blog name: mysite.com./blogone/article... or mysite.com/blogtwo/article...

How can I do that in the autoroute settings? My current setting is hardcoded: blogOne/{Content.Slug}

Comment: Did you try `{Content.Container.Slug}/{Content.Slug}`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Is there a documentation for these features?

Comment: Unfortunately no, all we have is here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Builtin-Features#OrchardAutoroute(WebPI) and it's not much. Copying my answer as an answer, so you can mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{Content.Container.Slug}/{Content.Slug}`